# C++: Consider the literal meaning of double quotes(") in a C++ std::string without using backslash (\)

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, c++17, stdstring

I've a JSON data received in string format.

```
std::string jsonStr = GetJsonStringBuffer();
```

> // It might get stored in jsonStr like this:
>
> jsonStr = **"**{"Key1":"val1","key2" : "val2","key3" : "val3"}**"**;

BUt JSON string itself has  double quotes (") in it. So when `GetJsonStringBuffer()` returns a C++ std::string is stored in `jsonStr`. Will it not create an issue as the double quotes(") withn the json data might be considered as string separator of C++ std::string.

How to handle this situation. Do I programatically append a "\" (backslash) for every double quote within the json string which i don't think is a great solution. Any better C++ solution for this ?

Answer (score 7):

There is no problem with a string having a `"` in it.   The only problem with double quotes in C++ is when they appear in a literal in the source code at compile time. And that's what the backslash is for.

Comment: Heck, thanks to [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) you don't even need backslashes. Useful for regular expressions, json, etc. `R"({"key":"value"})"`